# Removing NavigationController Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

the application contains more than one navigation controller. (example below)

```
NavigationController1 ----> ViewController1 ---> TabBarController --> 
NavigationController2 ----> ViewController2
```

whenever ViewController1 willDisappear i remove the NavigationController using `NavigationController.view.removeFromSuperview`

the problem im facing whenever ViewController2 loads. i just see a black screen nothing else. what might the problem be?

and what is the best way to remove the navigationController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The black screen is nothing but `UIWindow`. When you are removing NavigationController , the windows doesn't have any NavigationController. So you will have to set NavigationController for window as soon as you remove your first NavigationController.

You can try like this:

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

 appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = YOUR_NAVIGATION_CONTROLLER_OBJECT;
```

Comment: so whenever i remove the first navigation controller i need to set the window in appDelegate file correct?

Comment: No need to set from app delegate. You can use AppDelegate object for this. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: i get this error when trying to add your code my friend:  Cannot assign to property: 'appDelegate' is immutable

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help:

```
[self.window addSubview:secondNavigationController.view];
```

> Add the view of second navigation controller in the window.